# Update a Row from another row of same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `BaseProducts` table. I want to update a row from another row of same table. This is what I have tried but not working means not updation,

```
UPDATE DP
SET 
   DP.[Description] = SP.[Description]
   ................................
   ................................
   ................................
    ,[LastModificationDateUtc] = GETUTCDATE()
FROM    
    [dbo].[BaseProducts] DP
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[BaseProducts] SP ON DP.Id = SP.Id
WHERE   
    SP.Id = @SourceBaseProductId
    AND DP.Id = @DestinationBaseProductId;
```

I have `SourceBaseProductId` and `DestinationBaseProductId`.

Comment: "but not working," - and that means?

Comment: And the query returns rows without the `update`, but just a `select`?

Comment: Since you already have a `JOIN` condition between the two tables - why do you specify both criteria in the `WHERE` clause? Seems too much.... just try `WHERE SP.Id = @SourceBaseProductId` - that should do.

Comment: To join on `DP.Id = SP.Id` is not "another row of same table", but the same one. Your WHERE clause demands that this record's ID equals @SourceBaseProductId as well as @DestinationBaseProductId. This is only true when @SourceBaseProductId = @DestinationBaseProductId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you didn't mean to use an `inner join`, but a `cross join`:

```
UPDATE DP
SET 
   DP.[Description] = SP.[Description]
   ................................
   ................................
   ................................
    ,[LastModificationDateUtc] = GETUTCDATE()
FROM    
    [dbo].[BaseProducts] DP
CROSS JOIN 
    [dbo].[BaseProducts] SP
WHERE   
    SP.Id = @SourceBaseProductId
    AND DP.Id = @DestinationBaseProductId;
```

In this case you can have a different source and destination id, as you provide them in your where clause.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need of inner join. This will work.

```
            UPDATE   DP
                   SET  DP.[Description] = SP.[Description]

            FROM    [dbo].[BaseProducts] DP
                    ,[dbo].[BaseProducts] SP

            WHERE   
                 SP.Id = @SourceBaseProductId
                 AND DP.Id = @DestinationBaseProductId;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems all you actually want to do is this:

```
UPDATE BaseProducts
SET Description =
(
  SELECT Description 
  FROM BaseProducts
  WHERE ID = @SourceBaseProductId
)
WHERE ID = @DestinationBaseProductId;
```

Just a simple update where you you retrieve the value to be set. No need for a join at all.

Comment: What to do when having multiple fields? The query from OP seems to indicate that.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman: Ah, you may be right. AFAIK, SQL Server cannot handle tuples such as `SET (Description, Price) = (SELECT Description, Price FROM ...)` - which is standard SQL IIRC. So yes, for SQL Server you would need a join then.

Comment: Just looked it up. UPDATE with tuples (multiple column assignment) is standard as of SQL 2003. And SQL Server doesn't provide this functionality yet.

Comment: Good effort on the research. Too bad it isn't supported.